# Track emails to clients within web application

Tags: django, email, smtp, exchange-server, pop3

I am developing a Django-based system. It is kind of client-tracking tool.

Some users can work with different client accounts.

I would like to track the emails among users and clients within the application.

The company uses MS Outlook Server as a mail server and users are sending emails from their workstations.

The goal is to have the list of emails to/from users/client on the web page.

I see some possible ways how to do this.

- Make the email form on the web page and send all emails from this page. Thus we can store the email sent.
- While sending the email - manually add a CC field with the address of robot who will have access to this mail thread and can fetch messages from the inbox sorting them by the sender/recipients.
- Automatically fetch messages from user mailboxes (don't want to store their passwords though)
- Probably use some mail filter on the mail server to forward messages from/to specified address (don't know how to do this)

But maybe someone can give some advices? Any ideas, guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for something like the journaling feature in microsoft exchange-server. It allows you to define a special mailbox that will recieve a copy of all mails. You can find more information about this [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998649(v=exchg.150).aspx), [here](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/postini/docs/admin/en/arch_ex07_config/jrnl_ms_about.html) and [here](https://www.zensoftware.co.uk/kb/Knowledgebase/Archiving-Incoming-and-Outgoing-Emails-Directly-Journaling)

Once all the messages are in one mailbox you can access it from your application.

Answer (score 1):

I had done something similar a couple years ago (with Postfix, however, not with MS Exchange).

The best approach IMO is to setup a mailserver to blind-copy each email to your script. In Postfix this called a "custom transport". This way your clients will be able to send emails using any program, not necessary through a web form. AFAIK, nearly all production email archiving solutions work that way.